# Problem with adding element to a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

**Edit :** Solved, I was thinking that `temp` would represent the previous element's `next`.
I would like to add an element to a linked list at a position `p` (for the head `p == 1`), here's my function :

```
node* newE = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
printf("x : ");
scanf("%d", &newE->x);
newE->next = NULL;

if(l == NULL) l = newE; //l is the list
else{
    printf("Position : ");
    int p; scanf("%d", &p);
    int i = 1; node* temp = l;
    while(i++ != p) temp = temp->next;
    newE->next = temp;
    temp = newE;
}

return l;
```

The element isn't being added to the list, I can't see where the problem is.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you want to add node to beginning, `while` is not necesssary, if you want to put it to the end, also not necessary. Your `i` cannot be just there, you don't know length of list.

Comment: it means, while temp is not on the position I wish to put my newE in, make it point to the next.

Comment: I'm supposing that i know it.

Comment: If it’s not being put on the list then there is a key suspect area which is where you actually put it on the list, i.e. `temp = newE` - why do you think that might not work? What is the value of temp? How does a new value get inserted in a *linked* list possibly between two other elements?

Comment: in any case, to add new item to linked list, `previuos->next` must point to `newE` and `newE->next` must point to previous `previous->next`.

Comment: There you go, @tilz0R has told you. Shame, would have been good for you to work it out yourself.

Comment: I do not know why that might not work. Aren't modifications made with `temp` also made to `l`?

Comment: but in this case `temp` is previous.

Comment: There is no any modification to `temp`. Temp is just local variable and you modify where it points, not its members.

Comment: Thank you both, I have misinterpreted `temp` in my mind's eye.